# Not able to detect socket close? is trying to reconnect again after inputStream.read gives SocketTimeoutException a good way?

Tags: java, sockets, network-programming, inputstream, socket-timeout-exception

Not able to detect a socket close. Not receiving -1 when reading with inputStream. I am thinking about disconnecting in case of SocketTimeoutException and trying to connect the socket again. How feasible would that be?

```
socket.setSoTimeout(100);
InputStream dis = socket.getInputStream();
int count =0;
try {
LogManager.logInfo("Inside read thread before reading");
count = dis.read(buffer);  // not receiving -1 in case of socket close
} catch (SocketTimeoutException e) {
LogManager.logError("Socket timedout",e);
// should i try to reconnect to socket here
}
```

Comment: well your code suggests even more issues than the obvious ones. In your case seems like the stream is stucked, so at least one side either should `flush()` the channel or refresh it. In your case tho, imagine a simple scenario that you got the `SocketTimeoutException` while reading the stream , cause the other side is really down(after calling `socket.connect()`. You would need to handle quite a large number of possible errors. Also take a look at [java NIO](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/SocketChannel.html)

Answer (score -1):

> Not able to detect a socket close.

You haven't closed the socket, so there is nothing to detect. What you no doubt mean is 'not able to detect *connection* close', which is signalled by `read()` returning -1, `readLine()` returning null, or `readXXX()` throwing `EOFException` for any other XXX. I don't see any code here that tests this.

> Not receiving -1 when reading with inputStream.

If the *socket* was closed you would get `SocketException: socket closed`. If the *connection* was closed you would get the behaviour described above.

> I am thinking about disconnecting in case of `SocketTimeoutException`

There is no 'disconnection in case of `SocketTimeoutException`'.

> and trying to connect the socket again.

You can't reconnect TCP sockets. You must close the current one and create a new one.

> How feasible would that be?

Not in the slightest.

```
// not receiving -1 in case of socket close
```

See above re 'socket close'. If you're not receiving -1 from `read()` it is because there *is* no *connection* socket close.

When you receive a `SocketTimeoutException`, the socket is *not* closed, and neither is the connection, and there is no particular reason to close either of them. All it means is that no data arrived from the peer within the timeout you specified. Possibly the timeout is too short; possibly the peer is misbehaving. It is up to your application to decide which, based on the application protocol, expected service times, network latencies, ...

And 100ms is ridiculously short for a read timeout. It should be measured in seconds or tens of seconds.

Comment: Yes i meant to detect connection close instead of socket close, sorry for that, and i am not getting -1 in case of inputStream.read() , and if i try to reconnect when the connection is closed it gives No route to host. So is there any way i can detect the connection close without trying to reconnect the socket.

Comment: If you aren't getting -1 the connection *hasn't* been closed. It might have *failed,* and you might want to take the timeout as  evidence of that (but with a much longer timeout than 100ms). The fact that you get 'no route to host' indicates that something has gone pretty seriously wrong with the network.